# Print while($row inside a query SELECT tag

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to drive a $ row from a while to a "SELECT tag and i need to connect to all the rows from the while but I can not make it work.

An example that does not work but tells me what I mean is:

```
            while($row55 = mysqli_fetch_array($query))    {

                     $orderidtilsoog = $row55['post_id'];

                     echo $orderidtilsoog;
```

$orderidtilsoog is 2 or 3 post_id's rows, this post_id will i call in my $query103 but i dont know how to do it.

right now i only get 1 row but i want to take all rows from from $orderidtilsoog and connect to like:

FROM $v1.wpd2_posts where ID=('$orderidtilsoog') and ID=('$orderidtilsoog2') and ID=('$orderidtilsoog3')

```
             $query103 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $v1.wpd2_posts where ID=('$orderidtilsoog')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean IN?

```
FROM $v1.wpd2_posts WHERE id IN ('$orderidtilsoog', '$orderidtilsoog2',
 '$orderidtilsoog3');
```

if yes, then

```
$orderidtilsoog = array();
while($row55 = mysqli_fetch_array($query))    
{
    $orderidtilsoog[] = $row55['post_id'];
}
$q = "SELECT * FROM $v1.wpd2_posts WHERE id IN ('".implode("','",$orderidtilsoog)."')";
$query103 = mysqli_query($conn, $q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```